# How to unclog a toilet? (solid object obstruction)

Tags: toilet, drain

I just accidentally flushed my toothbrush down the toilet.  (Bathroom multitasking: bad idea.)

The toilet still flushes, but it's draining more slowly.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

Phew! After 15 harrowing minutes I got it out with a coat hanger.

I've learned my lesson. Multitasking?  Never again.

Comment: Rubber gloves and a little fishing around?  It's possible it's lodged just around the curve at the bottom of the toilet.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get at it with my (gloved) hands. Now I'm fishing around with an unravelled coat hanger...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the comments suggested, first try and grab it with your hands.  If it's passed the point you can reach, you will likely need to use a Toilet Auger to dislodge it.

[image: Toilet Auguer]
<sub>(source: [homedepot.ca](https://www.homedepot.ca/wcsstore/HomeDepotCanada/images/catalog/K6_Toilet_Auger_3C_4.jpg))</sub>

Tooth brushes tend to be problematic because of their shape relative to the trap in the toilet - they can really get wedged in there!  Worst case scenario it might not be removable.

Comment: Fortunately this wasn't necessary in my case, but thanks for the answer anyway. I'll upvote it as soon as I get enough reputation.

Comment: A last resort before giving up on the toilet is to shutoff the supply, disassemble it to remove the base, take the base outside and hit it with a garden hose on full blast from the bottom, reversing the flow of water and hopefully dislodging the obstruction.

Comment: @BMitch thats a really good idea, I never thought of that!